# global.asax application start without browser request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, quartz-scheduler, global-asax

Is there a way for auto start asp.net project?
I am using quartz scheduler, and i want to automatically start. I put codes in global.asax `JobScheduler.Start();` but here is the problem i dont want to any request to global.asax for application_start.
[Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/quick-start.html)

Comment: You don't have direct control over the lifecycle of an ASP.NET application hosted in IIS (though you can tweak it in the application pool settings). Therefore, running a Quartz scheduler inside is an awful idea. It's better to use a separate windows service, that can be deployed on the same server.

Comment: Thank you for reply, then i will use windows service :)